# Traceback accumulation only after Keyboardinterrutps

Tags: python, for-loop, traceback

This is my code:

```
import autopy
import time
import math
width, height = 400, 400
a, b = 200, 200
r = 150
def drawCicle():
    for x in range(0, 3):
        for angle in range(0, 360, 1):
            x = r * math.sin(math.radians(angle)) + a
            y = r * math.cos(math.radians(angle)) + b
            autopy.mouse.move(int(x),int(y))
            time.sleep(0.002)
def mouseMove():
    counter = 0
    while counter < 4:
        drawCicle()
        counter += 1
    else:
        print('Drawing ' + str(counter) + ' circles')
        print('moving once more in 10 seconds...')
        counter = 0
        time.sleep(10)
        mouseMove()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mouseMove()
```

The strange thing is that the code runs just fine. I only get tracebacks after breaking my loop with a `KeyboardInterrupt`, spilling out accumulated tracebacks from each loop that ran like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 27, in <module>
    mouseMove()
  File "test.py", line 24, in mouseMove
    mouseMove()
  File "test.py", line 24, in mouseMove
    mouseMove()
  File "test.py", line 24, in mouseMove
    mouseMove()
  File "test.py", line 23, in mouseMove
    time.sleep(10)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

This specifically happens only if I break the code manually, can anyone shed some light as to what best practice I am ignoring?

Comment: Just use `print` with `flush=True` to see the print statements immediately.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the output from your print statements immediately, just use [`flush=True`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print).

> Whether output is buffered is usually determined by *file*, but if the *flush* keyword argument is true, the stream is forcibly flushed.

```
def mouseMove():
    counter = 0
    while counter < 4:
        drawCicle()
        counter += 1
    else:
        print('Drawing ' + str(counter) + ' circles', flush=True)
        print('moving once more in 10 seconds...', flush=True)
        counter = 0
        time.sleep(10)
        mouseMove()
```

Exception tracebacks are only printed when you exit your program with an exception.

Comment: Hmm I am getting an invalid syntax flag with this `print('moving once more in 10 seconds...', flush = True)` do I need to do this in python3?

Comment: edit: I set `flush=True` however I am still getting the same issue.